# Is it possible to make 2 replace operations in 1 Regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text data like below

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

And I should return `'aaa','bbb','ccc'`

Currently I achieve this in 2 steps:

1. Replace  `[\r\n]+` with `','`
2. Replace  `($|^)` with `'`

Is it possible to do the same via only 1 step?

Comment: I can't think of a way quickly, but more fundamentally, why would you bother doing that?  As far as I can tell, it would simply obscure the code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Just out of curiosity, I am not very experienced with Regex, so I thought maybe there is a beautiful way to do it in 1 step, but I just don't know it.

Comment: You could possibly do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754501/212869 but for use it's just going to make things more complicated

Comment: Added an answer on the same lines as (and at the same time as!) the comment from NickSlash.  But again, don't use this in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a more robust solution with the same approach as [Scott suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555425/3832970), but my suggestion is based on *capturing groups*  that will be used to decide which replacement logic to use rather than listing all possible chars you need to replace.

So, here is the slightly modified solution:

```js
const s = `aaa
bbb
ccc`

const s2 = s.replace(/$|^|([\r\n]+)/g, ($0,$1) => $1 ? "','" : "'")

console.log(s2)
```

**POIs**:

- `/$|^|([\r\n]+)/g` pattern matches multiple occurrences of start or end of string or matches and captures 1+ occurrences of CRs or LFs into Group 1
- Now, with `($0,$1)`, we have access to the whole match and Group 1 (`$1`)
- If Group 1 is not undefined, if it matched, we replace with `','`, else, we replace with `'` (`$1 ? "','" : "'"`).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if this is just for curiosity, you can do this with a function replacement value.  I would never suggest actually using it for this purpose, but this should do it:

```js
const s = `aaa
bbb
ccc`

const s2 = s.replace(/$|^|\n/g, (s) => s === '\n' ? "','" : "'")

console.log(s2)
```

But of course, in some sense, I'm cheating, not really using the RegEx fundamentals here, only putting the logic in a callback function.

So, yes, this can be done.

But please don't use this anywhere.

(Oh, and I simplified to only checking for `'\n'`.  Obviously you could extend it to your `[\r\n]+` as you like.)

Answer (score 0):

No. At a time only one replacement keyword can be used.